# How to debug MPI application under Windows?

Tags: windows, debugging, mpi, mpich

I have MPI program which I want to debug.
I use mpich 2 under Windows, so does anybody know tools that can help me? Is it even possible?

Comment: You can debug MPI program using Visual Studio and mpich2 check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee441265%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have some experience of the parallel debuggers DDT and Totalview on Linux.  I see that DDTLite is available as a plug-in for MS Visual Studio; I don't think that there is a version of Totalview for any Windows platform.

So, yes, it is possible, but DDTLite costs money; however I couldn't work without either DDT or Totalview.

It's possible that Microsoft, who now produce an HPC edition of Windows, have parallelised their debugger but I have no knowledge of that.  You can use gdb on parallel programs, so an installation under Cygwin (or similar) might help you.  Personally I have never found gdb for parallel debugging anything other than incredibly difficult and I am fortunate to work at a site where getting a parallel debugger has not proven difficult.